# An uncaught Exception was encountered. Call to undefined method Admin_model

Tags: codeigniter

Okay i've cloned a codeigniter code copy and use it to designed a app, recently i wanted to start a new app and did opened the downloaded copy again and started to program, but now i am getting the the above mentioned error, this code worked in my prevouis code but in this it isn't.

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined method Admin_model::get_stock_item()

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\francois\application\controllers\Admin.php

Line Number: 239

Here is my controller

```
///<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
}

class Admin extends CI_Controller {

    public function __Construct() {
        parent::__Construct();
        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
            redirect(base_url());
        }

        $this->load->model('Admin_model');
    }



    function stock_adjustment($id)
        {

            $data = array(
                'formTitle' => 'Stock Management',
                'title' => 'Stock Management'
            );

            $data["data"] = $this->Admin_model->get_stock_item('', '', $id);
            $this->load->view('frame/header_view');
            $this->load->view('frame/sidebar_nav_view');
            $this->load->view('stock/update_price', $data);         

            $this->Admin_model->Update_asset($id);
            redirect( base_url('stock/stock_view'));
        }
}

Model

///function get_stock_item($limit, $start, $id=0)
    {
        ///if(empty($id)){
            ///$this->db->limit($limit, $start);
            ///$query = $this->db->get('tbl_stock');
            ///if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                    $data[] = $row;
                }
                ///return $data;
            }
           /// return false;
        ///} else {
            ///$query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_stock', array('id' => $id));
            ///return $query->row_array();
        }

    }

Please as i said it worked in my othered app but not in this one code is exaclty the same.
```

Comment: remove /// before the function get_stock_item ??

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I added the /// because of the site asked to add the ///. In my code i am calling it without ///

Comment: Hi I found the problem with my code i add my one function into another function in my admin_model.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear: The class `Admin_model` does not have a method named `get_stock_item()`. Probably beause you have commented-out the definition of the method.

Change the line

```
///function get_stock_item($limit, $start, $id=0)
```

to

```
function get_stock_item($limit, $start, $id=0)
```

There's a lot of other code that is commented and, as it stands, I think you will get lots of other errors running that model method.